# Symfony2 Architecture: How to separate data access from business logic?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building a Symfony2 application together with Doctrine. I have my Doctrine Entity objects in my "Entity" folder and I have some REST Controllers in my **Controller** folder. Now i want to add reusable business logic.

I'll try to give an abstract/simple example: 
Imagine you have a product which consists of parts. All parts have a price. You want to get the price of the product.

So you have an entity called **Product** which has an ArrayCollection (Doctrine ManyToOne / OneToMany) of **ProductHasPart** entities which reference a **Part**. The price of a product is the sum of the prices of the associated parts multiplied by the amount how often you need a part in a product which is stored in the relationship (ProductHasPart)

Intuitively I would just code a function "getPrice" to the product Entity, but this feels wrong:

- This would mix data access and business logic
- My Entities would get quite huge because those business logic functions can get quite complex
- This would make testing the Business Logic complicated.

**So where do I put my function "calculateCosts()" ?**

I have found so far two theoretical approaches: Services and Models. I read quite often that Symfony2 has no constraints on this, but I haven't found code examples for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can create service named Calculation. It will do cost calculation.
You also can pass not Product entity but CalculatedInterface. So code can be reused with other entity implemented CalculatedInterface

Example

service.yml:

```
    calculation:
         class: %calculation.class%
```

Service:

```
class Calculation
{
    /**
     * @param $entity
     */
    public function calculate($entity)
    {
       $entity->setTotal($entity->getValue1() + $entity->getValue2());

    }
    ...
```

in Controller

```
$this->get('calculation')->calculate($entity);
$entityManager->persist($entity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So am I correct with those rules?  

If I have complex computation, I create a Service. If I just want to store additional stuff, I put my code in the entity ("setTotal"). 

Am I also allowed to puth methods like special getters in an entity - for example a filter on an array colletion property?

Comment: btw: I think that the provided services.yml only works by adding `parameters:
     calculation.class: Vendor\YourBundle\Services\Calculation` which defines the "calculation.class" variable

Comment: Usually Entity used only for simple operation (getter/setter) without logic. More complex logic put to services. That will allow reuse existing code and more easy write tests. In services.yml you can provide class name as variable like parameters:  entity.class or write directly class name.